# Complete MOSS 2007 Migration

Tags: sharepoint-2007, migration, backup, restore

The situation at the moment is that we have a sharepoint server which started out as a pilot but now actually runs as the production environment. The server on which sharepoint runs is an old machine which does not conforms the standard requirements so I want to move the current environment to the shiny new server.

I've red a lot about migrating the MOSS services, databases and content and stuff but to be honest I am kinda lost in a sea of information and I can't find the right method to do this, I've tried to install MOSS 2007 on the new server as a clean install, restored the databasses on the new server, restored the backup on the new server which I made with Sharepoint Central Administration, alas, I did not worked :-( 
Lots of "Can't find this" and "Can't find that" errors...

It should be possible to grab all the data/sites/subsites/databasses/content/documents and everything else and restore that to the new server right?

Anyways, I was hoping for some step-by-step information... :-)

Regards
Erik404

Comment: Comment: The Sharepoint Environment also includes custom webparts/solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a way to do a complete migration...

Install a fresh version of MOSS 2007 on the new server (Server_B). Install the features and solutions you have on Server_A. Then use the SPContentDeploymentWizard which can be downloaded for free from CodePlex to make an export of all site content and import these on Server_B. Also backup custom databases needed by features and create these on Server_B.

I do have a almost completly equal server running now, some funky errors pop up now and then so I don't think it's the best way to do it...

Also, custom developed webparts need to be deployed manually to the new server, I didn't find a way to migrate these

Comment: To move the config DB:

stsadm -o deleteconfigdb

stsadm –o setconfigdb -connect –databaseserver <ServerName> -databasename <databasename> -farmuser <adminaccount> -farmpassword <password>

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.  The CodePlex solution is just a wizard GUI of what you would have to do at the command line via stsadm.

Essentially you:

1. Build the new server w/ all the patches, Service Packs etc that are on the old.
2. You will want to run a command at the cmd line to scan for and resolve any orphaned sites in your databases on Server A (command slips my mind but you can find it in TechNet - I think it's repair database  - something like that)
3. Limit access to Server A - so you don't have user changes during your migration.
4. Prepare the databases for migration - another stsadm command - stsadm -o preparetomove
5. Detach the databases from Server A.  Horrible command of -o deletedatabase - it deletes the reference but not the actual database (but still!)
6. Attach the databases to Server B

You should be good at that point.

As you've discovered - you can't migrate custom code, webparts etc.  These need to be reinstalled.  One of the reasons that solutions / features are really recommend for customizations.

Also - the search dbs, indexes etc. need to be recreated.  You can't bring those over.  But that's fairly straightforward - and makes sense when you think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Use these scripts if you need.

http://globaldeploymentmoss2007.blogspot.ca/